# How do I have a guest both record and call on a phone at the same time?

Tags: iphone

I want someone to talk on the phone while recording themselves on the phone, and later send me the audio file. iPhones let you record yourself, and they let you call people, but they don't let you record and call at the same time, at least not with the Voice Memos app. Is there a (preferably free) app that will let you call and record at the same time?

To clarify, so this doesn't get tagged as "home production": I work on a podcast. I use a professional mic, but my guests are remote and have to use their cell phones, so I'm trying to figure out the best way to have them record themselves. I imagine this is a problem for a lot of people recording for podcasts during COVID-19, since studios are closed in a lot of places.

Comment: There are several tutorials on this on Youtube. Search for "how to record phone call".  I would not say that it always is easy, but is doable.

Comment: I'd just look for an app that does it reliably for any phone. If there's not one, and you have enough cash, you could commission one - I bet there are lots of programming students looking to test their competence on a relatively simple project.

Comment: Why can't you just record the calls from your phone anyway?

Comment: I'm looking for good quality recording. Recording phone calls non-locally would be bad quality.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look for a method to get the 'phone' call right in the computer, then it becomes a simple internal routing task - Skype, FaceTime, Zoom, etc.

All free, non require a VOIP setup or hardware routing.

Comment: Thanks, but I've found phone recordings tend to be higher quality than computer ones, and that local recordings sound better than ones recorded over the internet.

Comment: Then you will need to look into tools to connect your phone to your computer via hardware or software. If you're on a Mac you can just use Handoff. On Windows I've no idea if it's even possible.

Comment: I'm not sure my guests are savvy enough for that. (I'm trying to get them to record themselves on their phones as they talk to me). Is there no way to call someone while recording yourself on your phone? Both features exist independently just fine.

Comment: Good grief, you don't want to do it that way! That's a tech support nightmare. Every user of different competence, on any number of iDevice/iOS/iPadOS versions, depending on device age, worse for Android with its 57 varieties of OS, which very few users ever update after they bought the phone. You'll spend an hour with each user before you get started, figuring out what they did wrong & why it won't work.

Comment: Nice Heinz reference there lol.